# Split string and store them into different parts of an instance field (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, object

I am writing a code that has a txt file that is a library of words

for example

```
V [ask%2:32:05::] [expect] require, ask
```

which is in this format

```
wordType(noun, verb) [token] [word] meaning
```

What I need to do is to split the string into different instance fields (the class ex. private String wordType)

What I have so far is the code to split the string to print into 4 different lines according to the instance field but I am not sure on how to assign each line to the class parameters.

This is my code:

```
public class EachWord
{
    private String wordType;
    private String token;
    private String word;
    private String meaning;

    public EachWord(String str){

        String[] arr = str.split("\\] \\[|\\[|\\]");

        for (String a : arr)
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(" ");

    }

    @return word
    */
    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }


    @return meaning
    */
    public String getMeaning(){
        return meaning;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return "["+wordType+" - "+token+" - "+word+" - "+meaning+"]";
    }   
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the tokens from the array to class variables. Implementation of your constructor could be updated to below to address your need.

```
public EachWord(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split("\\] \\[|\\[|\\] ");
    this.wordType = arr[0];
    this.token = arr[1];
    this.word = arr[2];
    this.meaning = arr[3];
}
```

One more point. You may want to add a space at the end of the split expression so that the token for meaning does not give you the leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the elements of the split to the fields:

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\] \\[| \\[|\\] ");

wordType = arr[0];
token = arr[1];
word = arr[2]
meaning = arr[3];
```

Note: I altered your regex slightly to remove leading/trailing spaces from the extracted terms that your regex leaves as part of the extracted term.